# multiple select setup causes error in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to simply select multiple options in a multiple select in AngularJS.

partial side :

```
<select name="usergroup"
        ng-model="selected.data.split(',')"
        ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in usergroup"
        multiple>
</select>
```

and controller side :

```
  $scope.selected = {data:"1,3"};
  $scope.usergroup = {"1":"groupe 1","2":"groupe 2","3":"groupe 3"};
```

Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fc7AZvgxBkAGGxapRz2t?p=preview) : i don't understand why i have all these js errors in the console, though the display is correct : the selected options are ok.

It seems from the error i can't use `selected.data.split(',')` but the selected data are ok.

This is a part of a "bigger" app, so :

- the variables format are like this for a reason
- $scope.selected isn't parsed (split) in the controller because, in the app, the selected data can be used untouched in other case (switch) which are not relevant here.

I would like to be able to parse the selected.data in the partial, is that possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answers is no, you cannot have the expression `selected.data.split(',')` as a `ng-model` attribute.

What you assign to `ng-model` must be a "Assignable angular expression to data-bind to".

If you have to use the provided `selected.data` string as an object you can use another temp variable for example `$scope.userselected` which then contains an array with the selected values.

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
        <select name="usergroup"
                ng-model="userselected"
                ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in usergroup"
                multiple>
        </select>
  </body>
```

You can then add a `$watch`-listener to `$scope.userselected` and in the listener assign the correct value to `selected.data`:

```
app.controller('testController',['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.usergroup = {"1":"groupe 1","2":"groupe 2","3":"groupe 3"};
  $scope.selected = {data:"1,3"}
  $scope.userselected = ["1", "3"];

  $scope.$watch('userselected', function(value) {
    $scope.selected.data = value.join(',');
    console.log($scope.selected.data);
  });
}]);
```

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sd2sdPk93nZav7s7z7Pa?p=preview)

Comment: That's so sad, because i've seen so ugly weird code in some html angularized attributes (ng-options is one of then). I thought there was a way to to it in the view. Thanks

Comment: I understand the principle, but in my case, i can't just use `$scope.selected` : the `selected` comes from a recursive ngReapeat : `<li data-ng-repeat="userselected in userselected.criteriagroup">...</li>` : the initial data is a object with nested subobjects

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-click` inside your `select-option`, so whenever you select option value is pass to `ng-click` function.

and no need to use `selected.data.split(',')` in html. use this in Controller.

Here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rnLCIX6WRTcMEYF5XP1b?p=preview)

**MarkUP**

```
<select name="usergroup"
            ng-model="selectedId"
            ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in usergroup"
            ng-click="selectedOption(selectedId)"
            multiple>
</select>

Selected value : {{selected}}
```

**Js**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('testController',['$scope', function($scope){

    // seleclted data
    $scope.selected = {data:"1,3"};

    // selected Ids
    $scope.selectedId = $scope.selected.data.split(","); // pass selected ids

    // userGroup
    $scope.usergroup = {"1":"groupe 1","2":"groupe 2","3":"groupe 3"};

    // ng-click function
    $scope.selectedOption = function(data){
        $scope.selected.data = data.toString();
    }
}])
```

no need to `watch` manually, since ng-click is work as two-way-binding.